# What pattern can you advice to solve a task?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, text-files

I have an assignment and I would like to figure out which pattern is better to utilize.

The task is pretty straightforward:

Develop an application that consumes various text files which differ from customer to customer, parses them one-by-one and persists into the database in a unified form. The application is going to be used by numerous customers.

For example, one .csv file can contain the following payload:

```
day,time,year,name,surname
01,12:00,2019,Andrey,Arshavin
...
```

Another file can look like:

```
day,time,year,fullName,country
01,12:00,2011,Cristiano Ronaldo,Portugal
...
```

And the database table has the following columns:

```
date(Timestamp),firstName(String),secondName(String)
```

The goal of the project is to provide a solution with a clear design.

The first idea that I have is to create different `DTOs` for different customers and one `Entity` class. On each .csv read, make a `List<DTO>` by using a factory method and after convert it to the `List<Entity>` and persist.

But how can I make it more extendable and maintainable? I think the spaghetti code is not a good idea for each new customer I will have to add

`"if that customer then return such new object"`

Answer (score 1):

Introduction: you havent's specified frameworks or libraries, so I suppose you'll code everything from scratch.

---

> The first idea that I have is to create different DTOs for different
>   customers

Given what you wrote, that means already knowing all your customers' file format.
Will they change over time?
Can you add a new class if a new customer emerges, or if one changes its file format?
If not, this solution isn't applicable.

> persists into the database in a unified form

This means you'll have a single database table where this data is going to be stored.
Given that each file has different headers, you need to prepare your table in a way to store all the possible headers, or map them somehow.

---

Then, you need to encapsulate the process of reading the file, parsing it, and persisting it.
My suggestion is having a proper class, which receive as input the CSV `File` instance.
This is how I imagine the code flow

```
final File file = ... 

// Program against interfaces
final Parser parser = new CsvParser(file);
final ParseResult result = parser.parse();

// Headers and Rows provide access to each field or row via getters
final Headers headers = result.getHeaders();
final Rows rows = result.getRows();

// Decorator pattern to apply headers mappings, to have a unified layout
final Headers mappedHeaders = new MappingHeaders(headers, mapping);
persistence.save(mappedHeaders, rows);
```

For the parsing phase, a simple, while clean, approach is maintaining each row as an `Object[]` or `String[]` array (decide if you want to apply conversions or not).
As you know, a CSV file has each field separated by a *comma* (`,`), which means you need  to

- read the first row, split it, and store the produced array as the *headers*/*keys* array.
   `headers = ["day", "time, "year", "name", "surname"]`
- read the second row, split it, store it in an array, which will have the same length of the headers one
- repeat for each subsequent row

This way, each array index correspond to a specific column name, which can be retrieved via the `headers` array.

Well, I've given you a general vision. It's up to you now, as you know the requirements better than anyone else.

Comment: Do you mean a parser for each set of headers? I can have a Map<Set of headers, Parser instance>, and for each file get an appropriate parser?

Comment: @Pavel No, the architecture must be generalistic to be flexible. The parser is specific to CSV files. You will not maintain pre-defined headers, you'll "calculate" them at the moment you'll read them. The only thing that must be stored is the headers mapping, for storing data into the appropriate table's columns

Comment: so, could you clarify please how can I store the mappings between columns along with rules how to operate with them?

Comment: @Pavel this is an implementation detail which will require me to do all the job for you. You can store the possible mappings in another database table, for example. For example, if in the main table you have a column named "surname", possible mappings might be ["surName", "sn", "name"]. This way you can also swap columns.

Comment: yes, I mean not how to store, but how to define relationships between columns? if day, year and a month than append and create date entry. Should it be a kind of util class with if-else statements?

Comment: @Pavel if the CSV doesn't carry useful information about the data type, you need to "guess" based on the header name. Or, you can store everything as String, and let the possible clients handle transformations.

Comment: @Pavel If you store mappings in a separate database table, you can also store their data-types. Consider it as dynamic/db-driven configuration.

Comment: @Pavel a database-driven configuration means you'll build your "MappingHeader" instances by looking at a database table (or more than one)

Comment: yes, I mean that's the main question, how should the mapping code look like? as if else chain, if such headers then map them to such header?

Comment: @Pavel I will provide you with a minimal implementation of the mapper tomorrow.

Comment: Currently, what I've did, I have different mappers to an Entity in which I utilize switch-case: if header == firstName { builder.firstName(value) }

Answer (score 1):

The clear solution will be to utilize some kind of polymorphism.
Instead of utilizing it `DTO`/`Entity` side, how about parser-side?

You will need to define an interface `IParser` with a method `List<PersonEntry> parse(String rawFileString)`

Each implementation for every customer will handle particular format. But every time it will produce the list of:

```
class PersonEntry {
    public int timestamp;
    public String firstName;
    public String secondName;
}
```

Some other class will be responsible for saving it into the database. let call it a `Repository`.

Next step to make your application more extensible, will be to split the process of parsing CSV file into 2 steps:

1. Parsing CSV string into some kind of `Map`/`Dictionary`
2. Extracting only interesting fields

I mean, you will only need extractors like:

```
 class CustomerAExtractor {
     public PersonEntry extract(Map<String, String> csvEntry) {
         PersonEntry personEntry = new PersonEntry();
         personEntry.timestamp = new Date(csvEntry.get("date"), csvEntry.get("time")).getTimestamp();
         String fullNameParts = csvEntry.get("fullName").split(" ");
         personEntry.firstName = fullNameParts[0];
         personEntry.lastName = fullNameParts[1];
         return personEntry;
     }
 }
```

for each separate customer.

**Edit**

I just understood, that your primary goal is to avoid `if`/`else` chains for each separate file format.

There are many ways to accomplish it. The one mentioned in your comment is one of them but has some risks (comparing predefined set of strings against actually read from a file -case sensitivity etc).

Other possibilities would be:

1. To implement `boolean isCompatibleWith(String fileContent)` in each `Parser` class, maintain list of them, then find the one returning `true`.
2. Very similar to point 1. The chain of responsibility pattern. Each parser is pointing to the next one to try to parse the file in the next step if it the current one cannot manage to do that.
3. (Only limited to CSV formats) Very crazy idea that came to my mind just now: How about making extractors as a dynamically constructed set of `mixins`? I mean to detect that header contains `fullName` field, then inject the following code:

   ```
   public PersonEntry addNextData(PersonEntry partiallyFilled, Map<String, String> csvEntry)
       String fullNameParts = csvEntry.get("fullName").split(" ");
       partiallyFilled.firstName = fullNameParts[0];
       partiallyFilled.lastName = fullNameParts[1];
       return partiallyFilled;
   }
   ```

Then detect that the header contains `date` and `time` and inject a code that can produce timestamp from them and fill missing timestamp field in the `PersonEntry` class.

For instance:

```
public class CsvParser implements IParser {
    @Override
    public boolean isCompatibleWith(String content) {
        return isProperCSV(content);
    }

    private boolean isProperCSV(String content) {
        String[] lines = content.split("\n");
        int headerSize = lines[0].split(",").length;
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line.split(",").length != headerSize) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PersonEntry> parse(String content) {
        IExtractor extractor = buildExtractor(cells.get(0).keySet());
        List<Map<String, String>> cells = new CsvIntoMap().parse(content);
        return cells.stream()
            .map(row -> extractor.extract(row))
            .collect(Collectors::toList);
    }

    private IExtractor buildExtractor(Collection<String> header) {
        List<ExtractorMixin> mixins = new LinkedList<>();
        if (header.containsIgnoreCase("fullName")) {
            mixins.add(new FullNameExtractorMixin());
        }
        .....
        return new ExtractorFromMixins(mixins);
    }
}

public class ExtractorFromMixins implements IExtractor {
    private List<ExtractorMixin> mixins;

    public ExtractorFromMixins(List<ExtractorMixin> mixins) {
         this.mixins = mixins;
    }

    @Override
    public PersonEntry extract(Map<String, String> row) {
         PersonEntry personEntry = new PersonEntry();
         this.mixins.stream()
             .forEach(mixin -> personEntry = mixin.addNextData(personEntry, row));
         return personEntry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a parser for each set of headers? I can have a Map<Set of headers, Parser instance>, and for each file get an appropriate parser?

Comment: @Pavel Better way, would be to have a class which can produce proper Parser/Extractor based on list of headers. Some kind of factory